# Neural Network Results always the same

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, python, keras

I have a GRU model which has 12 features as inputs and I'm trying to predict output power. I really do not understand though whether I choose

- 1 layer or 5 layers
- 50 neurons or 512 neuron
- 10 epochs with a small batch size or 100 eopochs with a large batch size
- Different optimizers and activation functions
- Dropput and L2 regurlarization
- Adding more dense layer.
- Increasing and Decreasing learning rate

My results are always the same and doesn't make any sense, my loss and val_loss loss is very steep in first 2 epochs and then for the rest it becomes constant with small fluctuations in val_loss.

Here is my code and a figure of losses, and my dataframes if needed:

Dataframe1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I6QAU47S5360IyIdH2hpczQeRo9Q1Gcg/view
Dataframe2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EzG4TVck_vlh0zO7XovxmqFhp2uDGmSM/view

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from google.colab import files
from tensorboardcolab import TensorBoardColab, TensorBoardColabCallback
tbc=TensorBoardColab() # Tensorboard
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import GRU
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import regularizers
from keras.layers import Dropout





df10=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Isolation Forest/IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)
df2_10= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/2019 Dataframe/2019 10minutes IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)

X10_train= df10[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X10_train=X10_train.values

y10_train= df10['Power_kW']
y10_train=y10_train.values

X10_test= df2_10[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X10_test=X10_test.values

y10_test= df2_10['Power_kW']
y10_test=y10_test.values




# scaling values for model


x_scale = MinMaxScaler()
y_scale = MinMaxScaler()

X10_train= x_scale.fit_transform(X10_train)
y10_train= y_scale.fit_transform(y10_train.reshape(-1,1))
X10_test=  x_scale.fit_transform(X10_test)
y10_test=  y_scale.fit_transform(y10_test.reshape(-1,1))


X10_train = X10_train.reshape((-1,1,12)) 
X10_test = X10_test.reshape((-1,1,12))



Early_Stop=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3 , mode='min',restore_best_weights=True)



# creating model using Keras
model10 = Sequential()
model10.add(GRU(units=200, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,12),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))
model10.add(GRU(units=100, return_sequences=True))
model10.add(GRU(units=50))
#model10.add(GRU(units=30))
model10.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
model10.compile(loss=['mse'], optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse']) 
model10.summary() 

history10=model10.fit(X10_train, y10_train, batch_size=1500,epochs=100,validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc),Early_Stop])


score = model10.evaluate(X10_test, y10_test)
print('Score: {}'.format(score))



y10_predicted = model10.predict(X10_test)
y10_predicted = y_scale.inverse_transform(y10_predicted)

y10_test = y_scale.inverse_transform(y10_test)


plt.scatter( df2_10['WindSpeed_mps'], y10_test, label='Measurements',s=1)
plt.scatter( df2_10['WindSpeed_mps'], y10_predicted, label='Predicted',s=1)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('/content/drive/My Drive/Figures/we move on curve6 IF10.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]